# kitchen - client.pem is not created on vagrant node

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm trying to run

```
kitchen converge <node>
kitchen login <node>
```

to diagnose problem with serverspec tests. When I login to the node I see that there's no client.pem key in /etc/chef, which leads to errors if I try to run chef-client:

```
Your validation client is not authorized to create the client for this node (HTTP 403).
```

though earlier it was executed successfully (no idea what changed).
Here are the questions I currently have:
1 - Does kitchen create client.pem by default on converged nodes?
2 - Is this key mandatory to run chef-client or there's some config options to disable it?
3 - For hell's sake, how to make all the stuff work again? :)

Answer (score 0):

This generally means you have Test Kitchen configured to use the `chef_client` provisioner and a real Chef Server. This is generally not recommended in favor of either the Chef Solo or Zero provisioners. Specifically this error usually means the client/node already exist on the server, probably from a previous test run.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger for the idea but I use `chef_zero` provisioner (it's set in kitchen.yml) and also the same config had been working earlier.

Comment: And `kitchen list` shows that all nodes are destroyed currently

Comment: I'm not sure Chef Zero is even capable of generating that error message. Please add your complete kitchen config include local and global files to the question.